# Why does Haskell insist on removing the last argument of a function?

Tags: haskell

This is the relevant code :

```
removeCard :: Card -> Tracker -> Tracker
removeCard card tracker = filter (\cTracker -> ctCard cTracker /= card) tracker
```

Haskell is giving me a warning here, saying it should be written without the tracker on each side. I find it easier to read my functions when all the arguments are there, as the argument names help clarify what the function does. I could reverse the order of the parameters, but it makes intuitive sense to me that if you're calling a removeCard function, the card to remove is the first parameter, so I don't want to do that either. Is there a strong argument in favor of removing the last parameter?

EDIT : The question originally said that Haskell was giving me an error, but that was a bug with Syntastic, it's just a warning.

Comment: It's just the style guide.  I personally find that after a few years of Haskell the point-free style is just as readable if not more-so than the point-ful style, but feel free to use whichever you like.  I will say that there are some instances where point-free style can make a difference in performance though, Haskell can in-line a function easier when it is "fully applied" as per its definition, so if it's defined with fewer parameters then you can "fully apply" it more easily.  This is really only important when you're trying to squeeze every last bit of performance out of your code.

Comment: It's just a practice people prefer, and I'm included. You've got currying, so it's just not necessary to type it again. I would suggest you get used to it by the way, not just because code will usually be like that, but also because (practically) you *have to* do that with function composition.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll just get used to that way of doing things, I'm sure I'll get used to it. Why do I have to do it for function composition?

Comment: @MarcusBuffett I think me means that you might have something like `map (length . show) [1..10]`, which uses point-free notation in `length . show`.  You don't have to use it, but the alternative would be `map ((\s -> length s) . (\i -> show i)) [1..10]` or `map (\i -> length $ show i) [1..10]`.  Most haskellers would very much prefer `map (length . show) [1..10]` because it's shorter and for most it's easier to read.

Comment: Oh okay, and if I don't remove the last parameter I won't be able to compose my functions?

Comment: @MarcusBuffett Don't get that idea, all functions can be composed no matter how they're defined, otherwise you'd have all sorts of confusing APIs.  The difference is that you usually don't specify the arguments when you're using the `.` operator because the extra lambdas clutter up the code.  Functions can be composed no matter how many arguments they have or which ones are explicitly defined.  The only real difference is there's a possibility for a slightly better optimization depending on how the function is defined, your code will still compile and work just the same though.

Comment: What bheklilr said is indeed what I meant. In his examples he didn't demonstrate it entirely however. And also, as he said, it's not about writing the last parameter in the function definition. The idea is to get used to applying a function except the last parameter, because when using function composition (point-free style), you always omit it, e.g. `length . filter (\x -> x \`rem\` 6 == 0) . fmap (^2)` squares a number, then filters if it's not divisable by 6, then gets the length. Notice how so easy it is to read it (from right to left).

Comment: ...the alternative would look like: `\xs -> length (filter (\x -> x \`rem\` 6 == 0) (fmap (^2) xs))`. See how it's (by so much) not as pleasant to read.

Comment: `filter ((== 0) . (\`rem\` 6))` :)

Comment: Your function doesn't have multiple arguments. Each "function" always has exactly 1 argument.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want this HLint warning, you can disable it. This module will not show it for any functions defined:

```
module Foo where
{-# ANN module "HLint: ignore Eta reduce" #-}

foo bar = show bar
```